# Peut-on mettre des « notes » en bas d'une réponse ?

Tags: support, markdown

J'aurais voulu mettre une note de « de fin » quand j'ai édité cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/prononciation-de-an-en-ain-et-in/1827#1827) (au lieu d'une parenthèse) et je n'ai pas trouvé comment, malgré une lecture que j'ai cru attentive de l'aide en ligne.

---

Is it possible to have notes at the end of an article? I did not find how to when I wanted to do it in this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/prononciation-de-an-en-ain-et-in/1827#1827).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je le fais d'habitude<sup>1</sup>. En mettant la référence en exposant avec `<sup>` et en mettant la note en petit en la mettant en indice (`<sub>`). La question a déjà été soulevée sur MSO, il me semble.

---

<sub>1. comme ça.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Les notes de bas de message ne sont pas officiellement supportées, mais on peut faire semblant<sup>1</sup>.

Pour un appel de note, utiliser les caractères SUPERSCRIPT ONE (¹) à SUPERSCRIPT NINE (⁹) (voire plus mais ça devient de l'abus, sauf peut-être pour des notes bibliographiques²) ou le marquage exposant : `<sup>†</sup>`.

Pour les notes elles-même, je préfère le marquage exposant ou un caractère exposant pour le numéro de la note, et le marquage indice pour le texte : `¹ <sub> Attention, ... </sub>`. Lorsqu'il y a plusieurs notes³, on peut les espacer de moins qu'un⁴ espace inter-paragrphe en utilisant un simple passage à la ligne : `<br>` ou deux espaces⁵.

¹  <sub>Attention, l'abus de notes de bas de réponse peut nuire à la lisibilité du message.</sub> 
²  <sub>M'enfin, en général les notes bibliographiques marchent bien dans le texte.</sub> 
³  <sub>Ce qui a vocation à être rare.⁵</sub> 
⁴  <sub>Non, ce n'est pas une espace.</sub> 
⁵  <sub>Là, par contre, c'est deux fois une espace.</sub> 
⁶  <sub>Ici, j'abuse volontairement des notes à fin de démonstration.</sub>

Comment: J'aime assez le fait de proposer d'utiliser les superscripts et d'utiliser `<sup>` dans le même message :)

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement je trouve que la gestion des notes de bas de question/réponse manque vraiment dans le markdown proposé par SE. Tout le monde a sa façon de faire¹. C'est vraiment dommage de ne pas avoir un format unique qui puisse être rendu différemment sur différents supports².

—
<sup>1. Par exemple ceci a été la mienne jusqu'à présent.</sup>
<sup>2. Les affichages partiels (twitter, feeds, newsletter et autres) pourraient par exemple omettre les exposants qui font référence a ces notes, car elles se situent à la fin et ne sont de toutes façon pas reportées.</sup>

---

In my opinion, footnote handling is something which is really lacking in markdown syntax provided by SE. Everybody does it differently¹. It's a pity we don't have a single format which could be rendered differently on different supports².

—
<sup>1. And for example, this has been my way of doing it.</sup>
<sup>2. Partial displays (twitter, feeds, newsletter etc…) would have the opportunity to hide footnote references, given that footnotes are found at the end of posts and are not reproduced anyway.</sup>